# Cannot open input file 'mysqlcppconn.lib'

Tags: c++, mysql

I tried to connect Visual Studio 2017 with MYSQL and it tells me that can't open input file mysqlcppconn.lib.

This is what I've done:

Configuration Properties-> C/C++->General-> Additional Include Directories ->C:\Program Files\MySQL\Connector C++ 8.0\include ; C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\include

Configuration Properties->Linker->General->Additional Library Directories-> C:\Program Files\MySQL\Connector C++ 8.0\lib ; C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib

Configuration Properties->Linker->Input-> Additional Dependencies-> mysqlcppconn.lib;
libmysql.lib

Comment: ***Cannot open input file 'mysqlcppconn.lib'*** This error usually means one or more of the following: 1. The file is not where you say it is or you have not given the correct path to the library. 2. You are mixing 32 and 64 bit or 3. The file is corrupt.

Comment: You may have to put quotes around each path with spaces. I just avoid this situation by never using spaces in paths where I put my libraries or code.